# Why does Firebase Google Sign-In require an API key?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-maps-android-api-2, google-signin

I have generated an API key in the Google Cloud Platform for the Maps SDK for Android, following the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key). My app also uses Firebase Google Sign-In. I am trying to restrict the key's access to only the APIs it needs to call.

I have observed that I must allow my key access to the Identity Toolkit API, otherwise sign-in fails. But in the Google Sign-In [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin) there is no mention of needing to generate an API key.

Anyone know what the connection is here? Why do I need to allow my key access to the Identity Toolkit API?